# How to increase the size of the "start-to-scroll" area while user is dragging and dropping?

Tags: javascript, html, scroll, drag-and-drop

The user can reorder list items by dragging and dropping them. The problem is? If they want to continue scrolling up and up to, let's say, reposition an item from the bottom to the very top? While dragging and dropping that item, they have to position the mouse cursor within an extremely narrow sliver of space at the very top of the window.

It's hard to discover that functionality (it took me a long time to even figure out I could do it that way -- and I'm the one designing the program!)

Also, even if you know about that functionality, it's very finnicky and if you even slightly move the cursor out of that tiny sliver, it stops scrolling, or the scrolling gets all herky-jerky.

Is there some simple way to increase the size of that area, where scrolling starts to happen during a drag and drop? That would make this much more intuitive and easy to use. Because the "default behavior" when trying to accomplish this isn't to position the cursor within a narrow band of 3mm at the very top of the window. It's to just move it close to that top area, maybe within like a 100 pixel area near the top or bottom.

Here is the relevant code section:

```
    var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.box .item');
    var targetEl;
    var wrapper = document.querySelector(".box");
    var itemClip = document.getElementById("itemClip");
    
    var scopeObj;
    
    // === Event Binding ===
    for (var j = 0, max = elements.length; j < max; j++) {
      elements[j].addEventListener("dragstart", handleDrag);
      elements[j].addEventListener("dragend", handleDragEnd);
      elements[j].addEventListener("dragenter", handleDragEnter);
      
      elements[j].addEventListener("touchstart", handleTouch);
      elements[j].addEventListener("touchend", handleTouchEnd);
      elements[j].addEventListener("touchmove", handleTouchMove);
    }
    
    // === Function Kits ===


    function handleDrag(event) {
      targetEl = event.target;
      targetEl.classList.add("onDrag");
    }
    
    function handleDragEnd(event) {
      targetEl.classList.remove("onDrag");
    }
    
    function handleDragEnter(event) {
      wrapper.insertBefore(targetEl, event.target.closest(".item"));
    }
    
    function handleTouch(event) {
      defineScope(elements);
      targetEl = event.target;
      itemClip.style.top = event.changedTouches[0].clientY + "px";
      itemClip.style.left = event.changedTouches[0].clientX + "px";
      itemClip.innerText = event.target.innerText;
      itemClip.classList.remove("hide");
      targetEl.classList.add("onDrag");
    }
    
    function handleTouchEnd(event) {
      itemClip.classList.add("hide");
      targetEl.classList.remove("onDrag");
    }
    
    function handleTouchMove(event) {
      itemClip.style.top = event.changedTouches[0].clientY + "px";
      itemClip.style.left = event.changedTouches[0].clientX + "px";
      hitTest(event.changedTouches[0].clientX, event.changedTouches[0].clientY);
    }
    
    function hitTest(thisX, thisY) {
      for (var j = 0, max = scopeObj.length; j < max; j++) {
        if (thisX > scopeObj[j].startX && thisX < scopeObj[j].endX) {
          if (thisY > scopeObj[j].startY && thisY < scopeObj[j].endY) {
            wrapper.insertBefore(targetEl, scopeObj[j].target);
            return;
          }
        }
      }
    }
    
    function defineScope(elementArray) {
      scopeObj = [];
      for (var j = 0, max = elementArray.length; j < max; j++) {
        var newObj = {};
        newObj.target = elementArray[j];
        newObj.startX = elementArray[j].offsetLeft;
        newObj.endX = elementArray[j].offsetLeft + elementArray[j].offsetWidth;
        newObj.startY = elementArray[j].offsetTop;
        newObj.endY = elementArray[j].offsetTop + elementArray[j].offsetHeight;
        scopeObj.push(newObj);
      }
    }
```

Thanks!

Comment: Hello. Did you find a proper solution for this? I'm looking for the exact same thing